# How can I use Latex in Markdown?

Tags: latex, markdown, jupyter-notebook

I want to write mathematical formulas in my jupyter notebook and it seems that `latex` is a simpler method to make them in `markdown`. I went through several links, but all of them provided me with different information. Please post any detailed links or cheat sheets which can help achieve the above.

An example of what I want to write:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jupyter notebooks [support LaTeX in Markdown cells out of the box](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html#LaTeX-equations) (via [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/), a LaTeX equation renderer built in JavaScript). Simply delimit inline LaTeX expressions with `$` and block expressions with `$$`, e.g.

```
Let $\theta^A_i$ and $\theta^B_i$ denote
```